# Visual Paradigm class diagram date attribute

Tags: types, uml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

I have a quick question regarding UML Class diagram drawing with Visual Paradigm. When I make an entity and create attributes, there is no Date data type available. I will try to generate SQL code afterwards, so I need to have columns of this type. What am I to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that UML does not have a "Date" datatype.
That said, you can add one to Visual Paradigm; [here is how.](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2270/2276/59851_datatype.html)

In case the link stops working: for Visual Paradigm version 14.0:
Tools -> Project Options -> Data Type .. change a language, add a new one or modify the one you are currently using.